# Can you create a 1-to-1 relationship between two query types?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

Say I have two query types, they both have a key column (as it happens, I'm querying an SCCM database by its views) called ResourceID.

The way I read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types) this may not be possible since a Query Type cannot be the principal end of a relationship.

Can anyone confirm/deny this?

I don't think specifics are required for this question, but if you feel they are I can add some.

Comment: Yes! You cannot create `one-to-one` between two query types because query type cannot be principal end of a relationship whereas in between `one-to-one` principal end of a relationship is a must.

Comment: Dang. Wanna put that as an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You cannot create `one-to-one` between two query types because query type cannot be principal end of a relationship whereas in between `one-to-one` principal end of a relationship is a must.